# ios view transition is getting distorted with setNavigationBarHidden=YES

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers, VC1 & VC2

In VC1.`viewDidLoad`, I have

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

In VC2.`viewDidLoad`, I do

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

But when I go from VC1 to VC2, the transition is not smooth. When VC2 appears, first there is a black portion in the navBar section of VC2 and then the proper navBar appears.

What should be done to make it smooth

Comment: call `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` instead? Make the call elsewhere, e.g. `viewWillAppear:`? (But in general I find this is just a flaw in the runtime; I see this "black portion" all the time.)

Comment: @matt I tried that in VC2, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

//Swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

//ObjectiveC

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false  animated:false];}
```